# Wireless stopped connecting in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo G50-70 2 days back,and the wireless was working fine. But since yesterday I have not been able to connect to the wireless network. The laptop detects the network, but can't connect to it. Cabled connection is working fine though.
Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
    *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 68:f7:28:53:ad:6e
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=10.0.79.15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:46 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0504000-c0504fff memory:c0500000-c0503fff

  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: d0:53:49:4d:56:37
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:19 memory:c0400000-c047ffff memory:c0480000-c048ffff
```

And here is the output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
uas                    24576  1 
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
thinkpad_acpi          86016  0 
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
msr                    16384  0 
bnep                   20480  2 
rfcomm                 69632  8 
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0 
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         53248  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
ath3k                  20480  0 
btusb                  40960  0 
bluetooth             491520  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
kvm                   479232  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
aesni_intel           172032  1 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
arc4                   16384  2 
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
ath9k                 147456  0 
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_soc_rt5640         94208  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
joydev                 20480  0 
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
snd_soc_core          196608  1 snd_soc_rt5640
serio_raw              16384  0 
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
mac80211              708608  1 ath9k
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                24576  0 
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
i915                 1048576  5 
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              524288  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
snd_hda_intel          36864  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5         snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
shpchp                 40960  0 
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  7  snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
mei_me                 20480  0 
drm                   344064  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    86016  24   snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
ideapad_laptop         24576  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
8250_fintek            16384  0 
video                  20480  1 i915
i2c_hid                20480  0 
dw_dmac                16384  0 
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0 
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0 
i2c_designware_core    16384  1 i2c_designware_platform
8250_dw                16384  0 
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0 
soc_button_array       16384  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0 
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
psmouse               114688  0 
ahci                   36864  2 
r8169                  81920  0 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
sdhci_acpi             16384  0 
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
```

Please help regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Drivers, 
I hope the above issue depend upon OEM Driver Issue.

The Same Problem happens in my Acer laptop also, I find the OEM driver reinstall than its work.

Comment: Where do I find the drivers? And how do I install them? Can you give links or describe in a little detail?